# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m getting this strace error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

This is what i want

http://localhost:3001/product/?id=5

Get the value of "5"

I´m using this code in Javascript

```
    var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('?=') + 1);

    var url = "http://localhost:3000/product/"+id;
      console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
          url:url,

.........
});
```

?id=5:161 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Comment: You're defining `url` ***after*** you try and use it...

Comment: Check the answer. Well organized and works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need code like this

```js
  var url = "http://localhost:300123/temp/?id=5";
  var id =  url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
  var newUrl = "http://localhost:3001/product/?id="+id;
  console.log(newUrl );
```

Then you can do your further operation

```
 $.ajax({
          url:newUrl ,

.........
});
```

Comment: `$.url()` is not a standard jQuery method

Comment: Not works, i´m getting http://localhost:3000/product/http://localhost:3001/product/ i want the id to concatenet with localhost:3000:product/  <- id

Comment: No, if you fix what i say, i make check

Comment: But what should i fix. Check the output it is correct. I don't understand where are you getting that from.  Look at this video https://www.screencast.com/t/IPY0zGzIJY

Answer (score 0):

your `url` should be declarated before its usage

```
var url = location.href; // just guess, how you use it
var newUrl = "http://localhost:3000/product/";
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
newUrl += id;

console.log(url, newUrl);
 $.ajax({
     url:newUrl,
    .........
});
```

Edited

Comment: And you are adding id without declarated?

Comment: sorry, I haven't noticed the assignment of the id in url.